# Join tables in PySpark on condition: if point is within a polygon

Tags: pyspark, gis, geospatial, geo

I have 2 PySpark dataframes: one with points `df_pnt` and the other with polygons `df_poly`. As I'm not very familiar to PySpark I'm struggling with correct join of this dataframe on the condition whether a point is inside a polygon.
I started with this code that I constructed from materials on [this page](https://ncar.github.io/PySpark4Climate/tutorials/pyspark-geo-analysis/geopandas-and-spark/):

```
from shapely import wkt  
import numpy as np
from shapely.geometry import Polygon, Point
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType

# Create simple data
polygon1 = Polygon([[0, 0], [.5, 0], [0.3, 0.2], [0, 0.2]])
polygon2 = Polygon([[0.6, 0], [0.6, 0.3], [0.6, 0.4], [0.7, 0.2]])
polygon3 = Polygon([[0.6, 0.5], [.5, 0.5], [0.3, 0.7], [0.4, 0.8]])
polygon4 = Polygon([[0, .5], [.2, 0.4], [0.5, 0.3], [0.5, 0.1]])

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'id':[0, 1, 2, 3],
                 'geometry':[polygon1, polygon2,   polygon3, polygon4]})
df_poly = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
    df, geometry=df['geometry']); del df


df = pd.DataFrame(data={'id':range(0,15),
                'geometry':[Point(pnt) for pnt in np.random.rand(15,2)]})
df_pnt = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
    df, geometry=df['geometry']); del df

# convert shape to str in pandas df
df_poly['wkt'] = pd.Series(
    map(lambda geom: str(geom.to_wkt()), df_poly['geometry']),
    index=df_poly.index, dtype='str')

df_pnt['wkt'] = pd.Series(
        map(lambda geom: str(geom.to_wkt()), df_pnt['geometry']),
        index=df_pnt.index, dtype='str')

# Now we create geometry column as string column in pyspark df
tmp = df_poly.drop("geometry", axis=1)
df_poly = spark.createDataFrame(tmp).cache(); del tmp

tmp = df_pnt.drop("geometry", axis=1)
df_pnt = spark.createDataFrame(tmp).cache(); del tmp
```

If we want to plot the first polygon we should launch the code

```
wkt.loads(df_poly.take(1)[0].wkt)
```

And if we want to check whether a `Polygon` object containt an object `Point` we need the following line

```
Polygon.contains(Point)
```

The question is how to handle this custom condition during the join procedure? 
The `df_poly` is way smaller than point df so I want to exploit broadcasting as well

**UPD:**
If I'd need to implement this in geopandas it'd look like this:

```
df_pnt
    id  geometry
0   0   POINT (0.08834 0.23203)
1   1   POINT (0.67457 0.19285)
2   2   POINT (0.71186 0.25128)
3   3   POINT (0.55621 0.35016)
4   4   POINT (0.79637 0.24668)
5   5   POINT (0.40932 0.37155)
6   6   POINT (0.36124 0.68229)
7   7   POINT (0.13476 0.58242)
8   8   POINT (0.41659 0.46298)
9   9   POINT (0.74878 0.78191)
10  10  POINT (0.82088 0.58064)
11  11  POINT (0.28797 0.24399)
12  12  POINT (0.40502 0.99233)
13  13  POINT (0.68928 0.73251)
14  14  POINT (0.37765 0.71518)

df_poly

        id  geometry
0   0   POLYGON ((0.00000 0.00000, 0.50000 0.00000, 0....
1   1   POLYGON ((0.60000 0.00000, 0.60000 0.30000, 0....
2   2   POLYGON ((0.60000 0.50000, 0.50000 0.50000, 0....
3   3   POLYGON ((0.00000 0.50000, 0.20000 0.40000, 0....

gpd.sjoin(df_pnt, df_poly, how="left", op='intersects')

    id_left     geometry    index_right     id_right
0   0   POINT (0.08834 0.23203)     NaN     NaN
1   1   POINT (0.67457 0.19285)     1.0     1.0
2   2   POINT (0.71186 0.25128)     NaN     NaN
3   3   POINT (0.55621 0.35016)     NaN     NaN
4   4   POINT (0.79637 0.24668)     NaN     NaN
5   5   POINT (0.40932 0.37155)     NaN     NaN
6   6   POINT (0.36124 0.68229)     2.0     2.0
7   7   POINT (0.13476 0.58242)     NaN     NaN
8   8   POINT (0.41659 0.46298)     NaN     NaN
9   9   POINT (0.74878 0.78191)     NaN     NaN
10  10  POINT (0.82088 0.58064)     NaN     NaN
11  11  POINT (0.28797 0.24399)     NaN     NaN
12  12  POINT (0.40502 0.99233)     NaN     NaN
13  13  POINT (0.68928 0.73251)     NaN     NaN
14  14  POINT (0.37765 0.71518)     2.0     2.0
```

[image: data]

Comment: Hm... I don't know all PySpark features and I have no clear representation what the schema is supposed to be proper for my case... But I added some info in my question in order to explain what outcome would emerge if geopandas was used

Comment: When you create spark dataframes `df_pnt` and `df_poly`, can you print the schemas? (`df.printSchema()`) and show some values? (`df.show(truncate=False)`). Not every pyspark user is familiar with pandas, so it's difficult to answer your question as it is.

Comment: The result of `printSchema` for both Spark df's
`root
 |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- wkt: string (nullable = true)`

Comment: The `df.show` for `df_pnt` look like this
`+---+---------------------------------------------+
|id |wkt                                          |
+---+---------------------------------------------+
|0  |POINT (0.2921357376954469 0.6871580673326519)|
|1  |POINT (0.6286913183363046 0.1356827455860742)|
|2  |POINT (0.8953860983142878 0.5851118896234707)|
|3  |POINT (0.3906532809342733 0.7742480793942560)|
|4  |POINT (0.2680620635805934 0.1676353319933286)|
+---+---------------------------------------------+`

Comment: The `df.show` for `df_poly` looks like this
`|id |wkt                                                                                                                                                                                                          |
|0  |POLYGON ((0.0000000000000000 0.0000000000000000, 0.5000000000000000 0.0000000000000000, 0.3000000000000000 0.2000000000000000, 0.0000000000000000 0.2000000000000000, 0.0000000000000000 0.0000000000000000))|`

Comment: The output is bigger but I've deleted some lines and characters in order to fit the comment section

Comment: Have you tried to look at libraries for spatial sql with Spark as [GeoSpark](http://geospark.datasyslab.org/)?

Comment: Not yet, but I'll try, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap `Polygon.contains()` in UDF and join tables on it. User defined function as a join condition are allowed only in inner join, though.

Create example dataframes:

```py
from pyspark.sql import types as T
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from shapely.geometry import Polygon, Point
from typing import Tuple, List


# create points dataframe
point = T.StructType(
    [
        T.StructField("x", T.FloatType()),
        T.StructField("y", T.FloatType()),
    ]
)

# point table
df_pnt = spark_session.createDataFrame(
    data=[
        (0, (0.08834, 0.23203)),
        (1, (0.67457, 0.19285)),
        (2, (0.71186, 0.25128)),
    ],
    schema=T.StructType(
        [
            T.StructField("id", T.IntegerType()),
            T.StructField("point", point),
        ]
    ),
)
df_pnt.printSchema()
df_pnt.show()

# create polygon dataframe 
polygon = T.ArrayType(point)
df_plg = spark_session.createDataFrame(
    data=[
        (0, [[0.0, 0.0], [0.5, 0.0], [0.3, 0.2], [0.0, 0.2]]),
        (1, [[0.6, 0.0], [0.6, 0.3], [0.6, 0.4], [0.7, 0.2]]),
        (2, [[0.6, 0.5], [0.5, 0.5], [0.3, 0.7], [0.4, 0.8]]),
        (3, [[0.0, 0.5], [0.2, 0.4], [0.5, 0.3], [0.5, 0.1]]),
    ],
    schema=T.StructType(
        [
            T.StructField("id", T.IntegerType()),
            T.StructField("polygon", polygon),
        ]
    ),
)
df_plg.printSchema()
df_plg.show(truncate=False)
```

Output:

```
root
 |-- id: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- point: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- x: float (nullable = true)
 |    |-- y: float (nullable = true)

+---+------------------+
| id|             point|
+---+------------------+
|  0|[0.08834, 0.23203]|
|  1|[0.67457, 0.19285]|
|  2|[0.71186, 0.25128]|
+---+------------------+

root
 |-- id: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- polygon: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- x: float (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- y: float (nullable = true)

+---+------------------------------------------------+
|id |polygon                                         |
+---+------------------------------------------------+
|0  |[[0.0, 0.0], [0.5, 0.0], [0.3, 0.2], [0.0, 0.2]]|
|1  |[[0.6, 0.0], [0.6, 0.3], [0.6, 0.4], [0.7, 0.2]]|
|2  |[[0.6, 0.5], [0.5, 0.5], [0.3, 0.7], [0.4, 0.8]]|
|3  |[[0.0, 0.5], [0.2, 0.4], [0.5, 0.3], [0.5, 0.1]]|
+---+------------------------------------------------+
```

Join tables on custom join condition:

```py
# join condition UDF
@F.udf(returnType=T.BooleanType())
def is_point_in_polygon(
    point: Tuple[float, float], polygon: List[Tuple[float, float]]
) -> bool:
    return Polygon(shell=polygon).contains(Point(*point))


# use UDF as join condition
df_pnt.join(df_plg, on=is_point_in_polygon("point", "polygon"), how="inner").show(truncate=False)

# show UDF value for each (point, polygon) pair
df_pnt.crossJoin(df_plg).withColumn(
    "is_in", is_point_in_polygon("point", "polygon")
).show(truncate=False)
```

Output:

```
+---+------------------+---+------------------------------------------------+
|id |point             |id |polygon                                         |
+---+------------------+---+------------------------------------------------+
|1  |[0.67457, 0.19285]|1  |[[0.6, 0.0], [0.6, 0.3], [0.6, 0.4], [0.7, 0.2]]|
+---+------------------+---+------------------------------------------------+


+---+------------------+---+------------------------------------------------+-----+
|id |point             |id |polygon                                         |is_in|
+---+------------------+---+------------------------------------------------+-----+
|0  |[0.08834, 0.23203]|0  |[[0.0, 0.0], [0.5, 0.0], [0.3, 0.2], [0.0, 0.2]]|false|
|0  |[0.08834, 0.23203]|1  |[[0.6, 0.0], [0.6, 0.3], [0.6, 0.4], [0.7, 0.2]]|false|
|0  |[0.08834, 0.23203]|2  |[[0.6, 0.5], [0.5, 0.5], [0.3, 0.7], [0.4, 0.8]]|false|
|0  |[0.08834, 0.23203]|3  |[[0.0, 0.5], [0.2, 0.4], [0.5, 0.3], [0.5, 0.1]]|false|
|1  |[0.67457, 0.19285]|0  |[[0.0, 0.0], [0.5, 0.0], [0.3, 0.2], [0.0, 0.2]]|false|
|1  |[0.67457, 0.19285]|1  |[[0.6, 0.0], [0.6, 0.3], [0.6, 0.4], [0.7, 0.2]]|true |
|2  |[0.71186, 0.25128]|0  |[[0.0, 0.0], [0.5, 0.0], [0.3, 0.2], [0.0, 0.2]]|false|
|2  |[0.71186, 0.25128]|1  |[[0.6, 0.0], [0.6, 0.3], [0.6, 0.4], [0.7, 0.2]]|false|
|1  |[0.67457, 0.19285]|2  |[[0.6, 0.5], [0.5, 0.5], [0.3, 0.7], [0.4, 0.8]]|false|
|1  |[0.67457, 0.19285]|3  |[[0.0, 0.5], [0.2, 0.4], [0.5, 0.3], [0.5, 0.1]]|false|
|2  |[0.71186, 0.25128]|2  |[[0.6, 0.5], [0.5, 0.5], [0.3, 0.7], [0.4, 0.8]]|false|
|2  |[0.71186, 0.25128]|3  |[[0.0, 0.5], [0.2, 0.4], [0.5, 0.3], [0.5, 0.1]]|false|
+---+------------------+---+------------------------------------------------+-----+
```